# Error while upgrading to linux-firmware/focal-updates,focal-updates 1.187.36

Tags: upgrade, updates, dpkg

I am facing this problem while updating firmware from 1.187.35 to 1.187.36. While upgrading this error message shows:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.187.36_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.187.36) over (1.187.35) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.36_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/firmware/ath11k/IPQ6018/hw1.0/m3_fw.mdt.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.36_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried solved using the following commands:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But same error.

Tried cleaning the cache and update, but still facing the same error

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-firmware` fix it?

Comment: no,still the same.
`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic`

`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.36_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: One other thing that might help, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  There might also be something in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677470/apt-get-error-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1 that might help.

Comment: any idea why this message is showing?


`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.36_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/firmware/ath11k/IPQ6018/hw1.0/m3_fw.mdt.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system`

Comment: Wild shot `df -h; df -i` and `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` please add this to your question through [edit]

Comment: I'm only guessing based on the error messages, but you might need to install the `ath11k` firmware itself before updating the Linux firmware package.  https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware

Answer (score 4):

I had a **very** similar case:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.187.37_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/firmware/ath11k/WCN6855/hw2.1/amss.bin': No such file or directory
```

Here's how I solved it:

Switch to the `ath11k` subdirectory of `linux-firmware` directory on the troubled machine:

```
cd /lib/linux-firmware/ath11k;
ls -la;
```

That thing has various product types:

```
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  9 hasan hasan  180 Mar 19 21:39 ./
drwxrwxr-x 98 hasan hasan 8100 Mar 19 21:39 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 hasan hasan   60 Mar 19 21:39 IPQ6018/
drwxrwxr-x  3 hasan hasan   60 Mar 19 21:39 IPQ8074/
drwxrwxr-x  3 hasan hasan   60 Mar 19 21:39 QCA6390/
drwxrwxr-x  3 hasan hasan   60 Mar 19 21:39 WCN6855/
```

The OP mentions `IPQ6018`.  In my case it was `WCN6855`.

```
cd WCN6855;
ls -la;
```

That has a subdirectory version `hw2.0` and a symlink to back to it called `hw2.1`:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 24  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 19 21:51 hw2.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    5 Feb 18  2022 hw2.1 -> hw2.0/
```

*That is the defect!!*

In my case the error was `'... /hw2.1/amss.bin': No such file or directory.`

Looking within `hw2.0` ...

```
cd hw2.0;
ls -la;
```

... we see:

```
total 6212
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Mar 19 21:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb 24  2022 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 May 29  2022 1.1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      71 Mar 19 21:32 amss.bin -> 1.1/WLAN.HSP.1.1-03125-QCAHSPSWPL_V1_V2_SILICONZ_LITE-3.6510.9/amss.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6158196 Mar 19 21:51 board-2.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      69 Mar 19 21:32 m3.bin -> 1.1/WLAN.HSP.1.1-03125-QCAHSPSWPL_V1_V2_SILICONZ_LITE-3.6510.9/m3.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  152394 Mar 19 21:51 Notice.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   24310 Mar 19 21:51 regdb.bin
```

So, `amss.bin` **is** present, but there's a triple symlink chain involved.

I simply deleted the top level symlink and then copied 'hw2.0' to create a new directory 'hw2.1' ...

```
sudo rm hw2.1;
sudo cp -r hw2.0 hw2.1;
ls -la;
```

... leaving:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 19 21:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 19 21:52 hw2.0/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 19 21:57 hw2.1/
```

I reran the `sudo apt upgrade` and the problem went away.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing your solution! I had the same issue this time with `/lib/firmware/ath11k/WCN6855/hw2.0/regdb.bin.dpkg-new`. Deleting the symlink and copying hw2.0 did the trick for me, too.