# lib-firmware upgrade fails

Tags: apt

apt upgrade fails with:

```
unable to open '/lib/firmware/ath11k/IPQ6018/hw1.0/m3_fw.mdt.dpkg-new'

/lib/firmware/ath11k/IPQ6018/hw1.0/m3_fw.mdt does exist
```

Anyone have a quick fix or some explanation as to why the dpkg-new file does not exist? I'm a slackware guy and out of my element on Ubuntu, particularly as this system resides on vmware in a data center I don't have access to.

Many thanks!

Comment: see this answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456089/error-while-upgrading-to-linux-firmware-focal-updates-focal-updates-1-187-36

Comment: `sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath11k/IPQ6018/hw1.0/m3_fw.mdt.dpkg-new` and then `sudo apt upgrade` Since the package manager is unable to open the .dpkg-new file, you can try removing it and upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick.